# How to lock my tablet screen programmatically

Tags: android, locking

When i was trying to implement lock the screen(when unplug the charger) using below code, it is not working. i'm new for the android can any one suggest me.

```
      case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING:
        Log.v("sunil2", "=======discharging");
        statusString = "discharging";
        PowerManager powermanager = ((PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE));
        WakeLock wakeLock=powermanager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "tag");
        if(wakeLock.isHeld()) {
             wakeLock.release();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot force a screen to lock using a `WakeLock`. The only way to force a screen to lock is to use [the device administration APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) and the `lockNow()` method on `DevicePolicyManager`.